# Allowing users to upload a list of supporting documents using Docusign

Tags: docusignapi

Our company wants to use DocuSign API to allow its users to upload a set of documents. Once a user goes through our online application, our application will call the Docusign API in the end and display the list of documents that they need to upload. Once the user is done uploading all the documents, then the admin should receive an email about the completion.

Can anyone direct me in the right direction..where I can find documentation regarding it? Most of the documentation talks about ESignatures of already created templates.

Thanks.

Comment: Your description of the process doesn't actually mention signing.  Assuming there actually is signing taking place, where in the process are the documents being generated?  Is it that your online application takes entered data, uses it to generate PDFs with that data filled in, then call DocuSign through the API to have them sign?

Comment: We need some supporting documents like pay stubs, tax returns etc from the users once they complete our online application. The data entered in online application is just getting general information from the users. This information is saved to database. After that the users will be redirected to a template in DocuSign which will list the supporting documents. The users will click on each listed document and they should be able to upload them. Once done uploading all documents, they will esign the template, an email will be sent to admin updating that all the documents have been uploaded.

Comment: I'm not sure you completely understand how DocuSign Envelopes or Templates work based on your last comment here, I would recommend you go through the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) for starters and learn more about how to use Templates and Envelopes.  Check out the Features section for more info...